# Find and all of a specific within an array?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that has one word in each row. I am trying to find a way to search the column for all the instances of each word, and to get a total number of occurrences of that word.

Comment: You can use "Sort & Filter" → "Advanced Filter" to get a list of the unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COUNTIF` function can count the number of instances of a word in a range.

For example, to count the number of instances of "hello" in the range `A1:A100`, use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "hello")
```

Comment: Oh my goodness - thank you so much! I had some really convoluted way of doing it before, but this is so simple and perfect. Thank you!